# Best way to iteratively construct a Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Let's say I have an algorithm that I am looping. It will return an unknown number of results and I want to store them all in a DataFrame. For example:

```
df_results = pd.DataFrame(columns=['x', 'x_squared'])

x = 0
x_squared = 1

while x_squared < 100:
    x_squared = x ** 2

    df_iteration = pd.DataFrame(data=[[x,x_squared]], columns=['x', 'x_squared'])
    df_results = df_results.append(df_iteration, ignore_index=True)

    x += 1

print(df_results)
```

Output:

```
     x  x_squared
0    0          0
1    1          1
2    2          4
3    3          9
4    4         16
5    5         25
6    6         36
7    7         49
8    8         64
9    9         81
10  10        100
```

The problem is when I want to do a high number of iterations. The mathematical operation itself is pretty quick. However, the dataframe creation and append become really slow when we do a big loop.

I know this particular example can be solved easily without using dataframes in each iteration. But imagine a complex algorithm which also performs operation with dataframes, etc. For me, sometimes it is easier to build your result dataframe just step by step. Which is the best approach to do so?

Comment: can't you just create e.g. a list of dicts that you then load into a dataframe after the loop? alternatively, you could also store your individual dataframes in a list and then use `pandas.concat` once which should save you some object creation time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's much more efficient to build a list of dictionaries from which a data frame can be created. Something like this:

```
dictList = []

x = 0
x_squared = 1

while x_squared < 100:
    x_squared = x ** 2

    dict1 = {}
    dict1['x'] = x
    dict1['x_squared'] = x_squared
    dictList.append(dict1)
    x += 1

df = pd.DataFrame(dictList)
```